# Collapsible Box in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

I have the following box:

```
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="tile-container">

    <a class="rectangle" href=" ">

<div class="plus radius"></div>

       

<div class="tile-label">

            Sample <span class="tile-accent">Text</span>

        </div>

    </a>

<style>

    .tile-container {

        display: flex;

    }

 

    .rectangle {

        background-color:#0051a5;

                             margin: 5px;        

                             display: block;

        cursor: pointer;

        height:200px;

        flex: 1;

        border-radius:23px;

        position: relative; /*must be relative to act a tile-container for the tile-label class*/

    }

    .plus {

        display:inline-block;

        background:

            linear-gradient(#73716d 0 0),

            linear-gradient(#73716d 0 0),

            #fff;

        background-position:center;

        background-size: 60% 2.5px,2.5px 60%; 

        background-repeat:no-repeat;

    }

    .radius {

        border-radius:50%;

        float: right;

        width: 25px;

        height: 25px;

        position: absolute;

        right: 25px;

        top: 25px;

    }

    .tile-label {

        font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;

        font-size: 25px;

        text-transform: uppercase;

        font-weight: 600;

        color: white;

        position: absolute;

        bottom: 25px;

        left: 25px;

    }

    .tile-accent {

        color: white;

    }

</style>
```

So I was trying to achieve the dropdown/collapsible feature by using a toggle javascript function but it was not working as expected. Basically, whenever a user clicks the blue box, the box should expand below with hidden text appearing beneath the main title, so its essentially like a collapsible button where if you click it, then the box expands out below

I tried using a javascript toggle function and adding a hidden-list css class and using that to toggle between whenever the user clicks the box, but it kept on displaying the text over the box instead of the box expanding, and the text displaying beneath the main title. The text was instead displaying over the box or the main title. How can I make it so whenever the user clicks the box, the box smoothly expands down, with the hidden text appearing beneath the title.

This is what I tried:

```js
document.querySelector('.rectangle').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('expanded');
  const plus = this.querySelector('.plus');
  plus.style.transform = this.classList.contains('expanded') ? 'rotate(45deg)' : 'rotate(0)';
});
```

```css
.tile-container {
  display: flex;
}

.rectangle {
  background-color: #0051a5;
  margin: 5px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100px;
  /* Reduced height for better visibility */
  flex: 1;
  border-radius: 23px;
  position: relative;
  transition: height 0.3s ease;
  /* Add a transition for smooth animation */
}

.plus {
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(#0051a5 0 0), linear-gradient(#0051a5 0 0), #fff;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 60% 2.5px, 2.5px 60%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  /* Add a transition for smooth animation */
}

.radius {
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 25px;
}

.tile-label {
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 25px;
}

.tile-accent {
  color: #FFC72C;
}

.hidden-text {
  display: none;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  /* Change text color as needed */
  padding: 10px 25px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  /* Background color for the hidden text area */
}

.expanded .rectangle {
  height: 200px;
  /* Adjust the expanded height as needed */
}

.expanded .hidden-text {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tile-container">
    <a class="rectangle" href=" ">
      <div class="plus radius"></div>
      <div class="tile-label">
        Sample <span class="tile-accent">Text</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="hidden-text">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: would you paste your javascript code in your question?

Comment: yes, I included what I tried in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you make the achor (`a`) a `div` and remove the "block"

- `.expanded.rectangle {` remove the space
- `.expanded+.hidden-text` add the sibling combinator ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

```js
document.querySelector('.rectangle')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('expanded');
    const plus = this.querySelector('.plus');
    plus.style.transform = this.classList.contains('expanded') ? 'rotate(45deg)' : 'rotate(0)';
  });
```

```css
.tile-container {
  display: flex;
}

.rectangle {
  background-color: #0051a5;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100px;
  /* Reduced height for better visibility */
  flex: 1;
  border-radius: 23px;
  position: relative;
  transition: height 0.3s ease;
  /* Add a transition for smooth animation */
}

.plus {
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(#0051a5 0 0), linear-gradient(#0051a5 0 0), #fff;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 60% 2.5px, 2.5px 60%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  /* Add a transition for smooth animation */
}

.radius {
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 25px;
}

.tile-label {
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 25px;
}

.tile-accent {
  color: #FFC72C;
}

.hidden-text {
  display: none;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  /* Change text color as needed */
  padding: 10px 25px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  /* Background color for the hidden text area */
}

.expanded.rectangle {
  height: 200px;
  /* Adjust the expanded height as needed */
}

.expanded+.hidden-text {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tile-container">
    <div class="rectangle">
      <div class="plus radius"></div>
      <div class="tile-label">
        Sample <span class="tile-accent">Text</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-text">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Perhaps what you really want is something like

- Simple `1em;` based on the container `25px` font
- no funky positioning
- No fancy sizing on the containers - the contents determine that
- put the "things" in a grid and size the rows and columns from that.  `auto` says use the contents size.
- Less CSS "fancy" stuff -  aside from the grid it is all about the visual style

```js
document.querySelector('.rectangle')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('expanded');
    const plus = this.querySelector('.plus');
    plus.style.transform = this.classList.contains('expanded') ? 'rotate(45deg)' : 'rotate(0)';
  });
```

```css
.tile-container {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.rectangle {
  background-color: #0051a5;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1em;
  grid-template-areas: "sample plus" "extratext extratext";
}

.plus {
  grid-area: plus;
  background: linear-gradient(#0051a5 0 0), linear-gradient(#0051a5 0 0), #fff;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 60% 2.5px, 2.5px 60%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.radius {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.tile-label {
  grid-area: sample;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 1em;
  height: 2em;
}

.tile-accent {
  color: #FFC72C;
}

.hidden-text {
  grid-area: extratext;
  display: none;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  margin: 1em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.expanded>.hidden-text {
  display: block;
   animation: fade-in 1s;
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tile-container">
    <div class="rectangle">
      <div class="plus radius"></div>
      <div class="tile-label">
        Sample <span class="tile-accent">Text</span>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-text">
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: When I ran the code snippet, the text is being displayed outside the box in your code

Comment: So when you click the box, and when it expands down, do you see the blank space it creates above the title? I would like the hidden text to be there if possible

Comment: Schulthesiss, does that make sense?

Comment: I added a "perhaps you want" example which really is a better way to do what I THINK you want - just change the visual related CSS to "style" things pretty as needed.  Note slight HTML change to put stuff in the "rectangle" container

Comment: Hey, yes however, is there a way to add the smooth transition which was there before in your code?

Comment: the smooth animation should be for when you click the box

Comment: I added a fade-in animation (also fade-out but not really using it) you can adjust that as needed, perhaps some combined transitions etc. but not really part of the question perhaps

Comment: not for the inner content.

Comment: I was mainly looking for the smooth animation after clicking the box, as when it expands out

Comment: Schuthesiss Basically, the same thing as in the older code of yours where after clicking the box, it smoothly drops down

Comment: the `  transition: height 0.3s ease;` doesnt seem to work in the rectangle class

Comment: That is about the `display:none` perhaps no need to go into that here methinks ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3331353/125981